# How to change the canvas image download location to user specific location?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

By using **CANVAS** I am taking a snap from web came.Here I created  download button to download the image.But while downloading it will downloaded into browser default location. But I my requirement is to give the user to chose download location.

Below is  the code:

```
<head> 
<script>
//SNAPSHOT
function snapshot() {
if (localMediaStream) {
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
// "image/webp" works in Chrome 18. In other browsers, this will fall back to   image/png.
 document.querySelector('img').src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
}
video.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);
}, false);

function snap() {
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 350, 320);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      document.getElementById('canvasImg').window.location = dataURL;
      document.getElementById('saveimg').href=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

</script>


</head>
<body bgcolor="#70c7f2" onload="onload()">
<button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Snap Photo</button>
<video autoplay></video>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="320" style="position: absolute;right: 0px;top: 10px; display: none;"></canvas>
 Save Here:
 <button><a id="saveimg" >Download</a></button><br>
 <img id="canvasImg">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here when we click on download I want to save that image into specific folder.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a *name* for the file by adding a `download` attribute to the link ([not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/download)):

```
<a id="saveimg" download="MyFileName.png">
```

However, having the browser prompt for a *location* where to save the file is something that the user needs to configure ([Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574), [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/startup-home-page-download-settings#w_downloads)).

Still, if you don't mind annoying your site's users, you can prompt them to use `right-click` -> `Save as` to download the file.

E.g.:

```js
document.getElementById('saveImg').addEventListener('click',function(event){
    alert("To download, please use right-click -> Save as.");
    event.preventDefault();//Do not start the download
},false);
```

```html
To download, please use right-click -> Save as.<br>
<a id="saveImg" download="MyFileName.png" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will display the canvas content as an image in a new browser tab

It also instructs the user to right-click-to-save.

When the user does right-click-to-save they can enter/browse to a download location of their choosing.

```
function save(canvas){
    var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
    html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";
    var tab=window.open();
    tab.document.write(html);
});
```